# Name validation with Regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with regular expressions. How should I write my regular expressions code to match following criteria?

1. It consists of at least two space-separated names
2. All space-separated names at least 2 characters long
3. At least one space-separated name is at least 4 characters long

I would like to write it with positive look-ahead code, `(?=...)`. Some examples of names:

**Valid:**

> Hendrik Argus
>       Jo Ha Kunts
>       Craig Wood-Stone

**Invalid:**

> Johannes
>       Hendrik A.
>       Ee Ff Gg

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What have you already tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Just [an FYI](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

Comment: Normally it would be this `^(?=.*?\w{4,})[ ]*(?:\w{2,}(?:[ ]+\w{2,})+)[ ]*$` but your bigger problem is _what defines a name_?

Comment: **[Sam Law](http://www.playtri.com/sam/)** will be disappointed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with following regex:

```
(\w{2,}[ ]+\w{4,})|(\w{4,}[ ]+\w{2,})
```

It matches word character in qty of at least 2 followed by space and followed by word character in qty of at least 4. OR opposite words.

```js
var words = ["Hendrik Argus", "Jo Ha Kunts", "Craig Wood-Stone", "Johannes", "Hendrik A.", "Ee Ff Gg" ];

var regex = /(\w{2,}[ ]+\w{4,})|(\w{4,}[ ]+\w{2,})/

words.forEach( function(word) {
  var matches = word.search(regex) != -1;
  console.log('"' + word + '" is valid name : ' + matches);
});
```

[DEMO and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jZ1zU4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for answering.

I resolved my problem by this line of code:

^(?=.*?[A-Za-z-]{4,})[ ]*(?:[A-Za-z-]{2,}(?:[ ]{1}[A-Za-z-]{2,})+)*$